# How to bind windows server 2016 to a domain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, nameserver

I have a domain that I bought from a third party website and I want to point it to my windows server 2016.

I have used a shared hosting before, and the way to link a domain name to shared hosting would simply be update the domain's DNS information to the purchased shared hosting NS.

I figure the idea would be pretty similar, below are what I did:

1- Installed IIS and created a website that I could access by using IP address.

2- Installed DNS Manager and used configure DNS server wizard to create a forward loopup zone. The forawrd lookup zone contains a SOA and a NS.

3- I went ahead and used the Nameserver in the lookup zone to update the nameserver in my third party domain.

It has been 10 hours, everytime I go to the domain site, I will receive error message saying "server IP address could not be found."

Can anyone help? Let me know if need additional information.. thanks!

Comment: You can update a third party registrar or DNS host to add an A record that points to your server’s public IP easy enough. But you can’t, or at least shouldn’t, try to host your own DNS. There are several technical hurdles. DNS infrastructure is critical, and it should be left to hosting providers, especially being it is typically free from your registrar.

Comment: If you really want to host the DNS zone yourself, you should provide more technical details. Also, you always need at least two name servers. Your Windows 2016 server will be one. Which server will be the second one?

Comment: @Appleoddity  thanks, the issue is now resloved... I mixed the two concepts together, in the service provider I added a A record and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an 'A' record to your ISP's DNS. Your own ('private') DNS will most likely never get a domain name delegation.

Comment: Got it solved a few days ago, this was indeed my solution..  Thanks for the answer though!